# return lines that contains a specifc word

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset in Python (Pandas) that needs to be checked on forbidden words. When I run the script, only the lines with forbidden words should occur. However, sometimes the forbidden word is part of a larger word that is not forbidden. In that case that line should not occur.

For example the following forbidden words: ***"psycho", "fool", "stupid"**.*

This is some text in the column of my dataset:
***"This doctor is a psycho"

"I had a psychotherapy that worked for me"***

The script should only return line 1, not line 2. But my script returns both lines:
***df_match=df[df['column'].str.contains("fool|stupid|psycho")==True]***

And this script returns no line at all, because it searches for ONLY the word "psycho", while my lines contain more words:
***df_match=df[df['column'].str.contains("fool|stupid|^psycho$")==True]***

Who can help me change this script correctly in order to let it work?

Comment: Hint: `\b` means "word boundary" (beginning/end of a word), so `"\bpsycho\b"` should match "This doctor is a psycho", but not "I had a psychotherapy that worked for me"…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Błotosmętek points out you can use word boundaries in regex:

```
s = pd.Series(["This doctor is a psycho", "I had a psychotherapy that worked for me"])
words = ["psycho", "fool", "stupid"]
reglist = [r'\b'+i+r'\b' for i in words]
s.str.contains('|'.join(reglist))
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

And, filtering:

```
s[s.str.contains('|'.join(reglist))]
```

Output:

```
0    This doctor is a psycho
dtype: object
```

*Note:*  No need to use `==True` because you are already returned a boolean series.

Comment: Scott, thanks for your answer. Do you also know if it is possible to return an extra column with the specific forbidden word that is matched? Sometimes the text is very long, so we can see instantly what forbidden word occurs (my original list with forbidden words is very long). Thank you!

Comment: Yes, we can use .str.extract to extract the forbidden word.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to do a little change to your code. Here it is:

```
df_match=df[df['column'].str.contains(r"\bfool\b|\bstupid\b|\bpsycho\b")==True]
```